# Execute logcat with tag on Android returns empy

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I have an Activity which every second write a counter to the logcat:

```
Runnable rLog = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        i++;
        Log.d("bbb", "i= " + i);
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);                
    }
};
```

In addition - I have a service which read from "logcat -s bbb" and log it:

```
Runnable rGetLog = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = null;
        try {
            process = rt.exec("logcat -s bbb");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        try {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                Log.d("aaa", "get line = " + line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }               
    }
};
```

This code works well. The problem starts when I change the tag "bbb" to a real tag such as "AndroidRuntime" or another tag... **I got an empty response from logcat**
(if I run at the same time "logcat -s AndroidRuntime" from adb I got lots of lines...)

Who knows what the problem is? what can be different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Android Jelly Bean, applications cannot read log entries from other applications, unless your device is rooted and you read the logs as superuser.

try using sudo to get permissions:
process = rt.exec("su && logcat -s YOUR_TAG");